# Adjustbox not showing caption with key option chosen

Tags: tables, adjustbox

I can't get a caption to show up in the following MWE.

I've put `caption` at the end of the key list, and in the actual example the `BLAH BLAH BLAH` is replaced with an `\input{table.tex}` variant, but the problem persists in this simple version. `\caption` outside the environment just gives me a `caption outside float environment` error.

Any thoughts appreciated

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio,caption={blah blah}}
BLAH BLAH BLAH
\end{adjustbox}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `caption` key only sets the caption text. It will only be used if you also use a `figure`, `float` or `nofloat` key. The package manual states this:

> `caption=<caption text>`
>   `caption=[<short caption>]{<long caption>}`
>
> Defines a caption which will be used by a following `figure`, `float` or `nofloat` key.
>   The position of the caption defaults to top for a table (non-)float and bottom for
>   every other type.

If you don't want to turn the content into a float, use `nofloat`. Please note that you need to setup the caption type yourself using an appropriate package. This is not done for you by `adjustbox`. Also, there is no support for an unnumbered caption, e.g. just some title text etc., therefore using an existing float/caption type is mandatory.

---

Unfortunately the mentioned keys don't work directly with the `width`, `height` or `totalheight` keys because they don't force the execution of the outstanding resizing operations. Because of this the environment will try to resize the whole (non-)float environment which causes an error. I will fix this in the next version of `adjustbox`. In the meantime simply use a `rotate=0` to force the resizing operation.

---

Here a minimal example where the adjusted content is taken as a `table`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio,rotate=0,caption={blah blah},float=table}
BLAH BLAH BLAH
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @MartinScharrer the `rotate=0` was what I was looking for. Appreciate your help. Really useful package too btw. Thank you.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha: I'm glad that I could help. I already fixed the issue in the code repository, so the next release will not require the `rotate=0` workaround.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha: `adjustbox` v1.1 2018/04/08 fixes the problem and makes `rotate=0` unneeded in this case.